# How to change cart page in woocommerce due to the changing of the user?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, session-cookies, cart

I am using woocommerce plugin in WP and having different users .. when user A added some products to his cart page then log out and then User B tried to add some other products to his cart his cart page shows what User A has added to the cart .. I hope you could help

Comment: Dear Mario, Please make sure that you are talking about logged in users. It can be a confusion that you are seeing the same products in the cart, else new logged in user will have it's own session and items in cart. They cannot be the same.

Comment: yes i checked for logged in users.. user A has the same order on his cart as user B do and i am using localhost

Comment: Strange, never heard it before. Any recorded video or screenshot so we can understand this situation better?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nT-QC5ek8osNrFIYMQ_oy1GrJjI2YmjE/view?usp=sharing
you can view the problem in the shared link

Comment: I appreciate that you recorded a video to show me. But this was something already in your cart. Can you try like, login from one user and add to cart another item so it will be 2 items in the cart. Logout and login from another user, add a different item in the cart this time. Now logout and double check both users with login parallel, using a normal browser and incognito at the same time. Please do this so we can troubleshoot it better.